# Getting Order Number from Order Id in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am using  following code to get the Order Number from Order ID.

```
$orderId=64; //Order Id will be supplied dynamically

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

echo "Order Number is: ".$order['increment_id'];
```

I am getting the correct order number using this code like 100000067.

I wanted to know Is this the correct approach to use.

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have followed the same way when required.

Comment: try echo $order->getIncrementId(); ^^

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
$orderId = 64;
$order   = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

echo $order->getIncrementId();
```

Cheers!