# Get order id in Magento from order data in Wyomind Order Export tool module

Tags: php, magento

How can i get the order_id (entity or increment id) in Magento backend dynamically? I have found a lot of examples where the order id is supplied as a static value. See [Getting Order Number from Order Id in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141813/getting-order-number-from-order-id-in-magento) for example.

I want to supply the order_id from a current scope, so the current order id of the order. Maybe this should be referenced with the help of "$this". This is a example i came across:

```
$orderId = 64;
$order   = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

echo $order->getIncrementId();
```

I would like the info in a back-end module, not on the succes page or in front-end.

Comment: You want to get some order data? Where in Magento are you, checkout flow / cart? Customer Data? You will need some way to connect to a order to get a relevant id. If you just want one random id that is different.

Comment: Customer data from an order in Magento backend. I think we can get it from sales/order object? Eventually i need to get the street and housenumber from an order. To retrieve this i need the order id from an order

Comment: How will you identify the order you want to extract information from? Or do you want to do it for all orders?

Comment: I have to give you some background information. I'm using a module in Magento to generate a CSV file from an order. I need the order_id to finally retrieve the streetname and housenumber. To populate this cell in the CSV you can use PHP custom attributes. You can manually enter PHP data to get the value you want. When executing exactly the code that is mentioned in the first post ($order_id = 64, etc) i get the increment_id as response. In this example the order_id is static. We need to get some code before this PHP code to get the order_id dynamically. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, It seems the module already loads the data. There is probably a way to get the data using the modules methods. What module are you using?

Comment: I'm using Wyomind's Order Export tool. On the support page you will see some snippets

Comment: https://www.wyomind.com/orders-export-tool-magento.html -> user guide -> library. It has a list of items. If you have further questions open a new question, or for help with this module, modify your question to include the module you are using.

Comment: I have checked the options listed in this module and have had contact with the support department. The said i could use PHP code, and that was it. For customisations i have to pay which i have done so far for two customisations . Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments you are using [Wyomind's Order Export tool](http://wyomind.com/orders-export-tool-magento.html) and you are trying to retrieve the **order_id** or the **increment_id** with the custom PHP code option the module offers. (*STEP 4: Create your custom attributes*).

To do this you can use the $item variable. As per their documentation the $item variable contains the current order.

So:

```
$orderId = $item->getId();
$orderIncrementId = $item->getIncrementId();
```

Will get you the two values your question asks about.

---

**Note:** You may be better served using built in methods.

```
{firstname shipping} {lastname shipping} 
{postcode shipping} {street shipping,[implode]}
{city shipping} {country_id shipping}
```

Where **{street shipping,[implode]}** looks on point. (Based on your comments).

Comment: I have done that. I implodes the streetname and housenumber. How can i get a seperate value, so streetname and housenumber in a seperate cell/field?

Comment: You can try to omit the [implode] tag. really you should ask the vendor. I have no way of knowing what is available in this module.

Answer (score 1):

Another shorthand is to use the following code directly in the pattern in the template:

```
<? return str_replace(".","","{base_price_incl_tax product}"); ?>
```

In this way you don't have to create a custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It works now by using the following code:

```
$orderId = $item->getId();
$orderIncrementId = $item->getIncrementId();
```

To retrieve the housenumber or street i used:

```
$orderId = $item->getId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
// For getting Customer Order Info
$billing_housenumber = $order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet(2);
return $billing_housenumber;
$billing_street = $order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet(1);
return $billing_street;
```

You have to use the return value to "print" the value in the CVS/XML.